Проблема с получением метаданных с помощью библиотеки yt-dlp с YouTube
У меня проблема с использованием библиотеки yt-dlp для загрузки видео с YouTube
При получении названия видео иногда программа выдает неправильное название, которого вообще не существует. Я получаю название видео с помощью ['title']
Я использую php для запроса
Не могли бы вы подсказать мне, как сделать более стабильные запросы для получения названия видео?
Вот код:
            $metadata_command = "$yt_dlp_path --dump-json --verbose \"$user_url\"";
            $metadata_output = [];
            $metadata_return_var = 0;
            exec($metadata_command, $metadata_output, $metadata_return_var);
            if ($metadata_return_var !== 0) {
                echo "Metadata retrieval error: " . implode("\n", $metadata_output);
                throw new Exception('Metadata retrieval error video from YouTube');
            }
            if ($metadata_return_var === 0) {
                $metadata = json_decode(implode("\n", $metadata_output), true);
                if ($metadata === null) {
                    throw new Exception('Error decoding JSON metadata.');
                }
                $video_title = $metadata['title'];
            }


добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как задать хороший вопрос
